# Push notification is not working in iOS 9.2

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9.2

App is not receiving Push Notification message after upgrading my iPhone device to iOS 9.2 and I checked my app is available in Notification Center and disable the "Do Not Distrub" option in my device.

It was working before updating to iOS 9.2 and I have checked stack overflow solutions but still I am facing the same issue.

Please help me to sort out this issue?.

Comment: How are you testing it?

Comment: I am sending the notification message from local server with the help of APNS and checking the messages in iPhone 6 with iOS 9.2 device.

Comment: you have used https server for sending push notification ?

Comment: You're definitely definitely absolutely definitely using the correct device token?

Comment: What's the APNS response?

Comment: @Tokn Yes, I am using the correct device token.

Comment: @raj have you got this answer?

Comment: @raj any update on this question?

Comment: Hey developer i have same issue but some time i get notification and some time not when i restart my device but not working .. please help me to find bugs. i have received all notification with other version of device. Thanks